# How to process subscription billing in the desktop app?

Tags: architecture, in-app-billing, billing

I'm an individual developer and I'm going to intoduce a subscription fee for certain features in my cross-platform app. I don't know how to implement and maintain such thing money/billing -wise.

- How do I implement billing? On my own or through third-party? Which is better for indie?
- Do I need to collect billing credentials (like card number etc.) and if yes are there any compliance rules for that?

Where "better" means less prone to an error for novice but at the same time less money wasted for fees (as for an indie).

Comment: Implementing billing is not necessarily something you want to do without having done it many times before. There's dozens of pre-existing billing platforms you can leverage, both those operated as a service (e.g. PayPal, Cheddar Getter, Stripe) and software packages. **DO NOT** build your own unless you've done this before. Academic implementations can cost you when mistakes happen and you start leaking huge amounts of money.

Comment: @tadman by your logic, nobody would ever implement billing (i.e. don't do it unless you've already done it). :)  Joking, of course.  Agreed that it's better to adopt an existing mechanism.

Comment: First you work on someone else's billing system, then you build one with the supervision of someone who knows how it's supposed to work, and later after you've built maybe four or five of those, then you can go and build your own. Easy! I say this half-jokingly because these things are notoriously fussy to get right and even tiny mistakes can mean having to contact all your customers for billing adjustments, or worse, having to eat the costs of incorrectly billing people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question will likely be closed for being too many questions and being a request for third party resources.  That said, I'll try and help.

- Should it be better done in the app or through the website?

  Better is a matter of opinion; you don't provide any criteria for what it means to be better or worse.
- How do I implement billing? On my own or through third-party? Which is better for indie?

  100% do not implement it yourself.  You need to work with a third party like Paypal or Braintree or similar payment gateways, who can provide you sample code and integration guidance.

  - Do I need to collect billing credentials (like card number etc.) and if yes are there any compliance rules for that? Any
    well-adopted open-source solutions for processing sales/refunds
    available nowadays?

  All this will depend on your payment gateway.  If you don't know what you're doing, the best way is to let them handle all of that, and all you do is integrate with them.  In that case, it'll be a series of calls to their API that will direct your user to them, and then give you confirmation that the user is paid, etc. The good ones will also handle refunds for you as well.  As for compliance, yes.  If you are handling payment information you have to be PCI (Payment Card Industry) compliant.  All the more reason to integrate with a third party who already knows how to do that rather than trying to collect yourself.

Comment: PCI is serious business. Even more serious is knowing your [threats](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Cheat_Sheet_Series).

Comment: @Paul, thanks. I've updated what "better" means. I meant less prone to make an error for novice but at the same time not wasting much on fees (for an indie developer)

Comment: OK, that doesnt' change my answer.